# How to resize/scale table on smaller screens (Bootstrap4) without scrollbar?

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries, css-tables

I have some problems with my table.

Well, my idea: on smaller screens, table have to resize/scale but I want to avoid scrollbars (the reason because I didn't use table-responsive class).

I just want self-resizing table that fits mobile screen (something like zoom out when it is on mobile). Is this achievable?

I am using bootstrap4, and I have tried some solutions (media queries etc.) but unlucky.

At this moment, only 1/2 of my table sits on mobile screen, rest overlaps screen.

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/b9Lw06nt/

```
<section id="x" class="x">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table borderless">
      <tr>
        <td valign=middle>
          <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
              <td colspan=3 align=center height=90 class="x1" valign=top>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width=400 align=right valign=top>
                Lorem ipsum
              </td>
              <td width=45 align=center>
                Lorem ipsum
              </td>
              <td width=400 align=left valign=top>
                Lorem ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right class=x2>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td width=45 align=center>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td align=left class=x2>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right class=x2k>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td width=45 align=center>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td align=left class=x2>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align=right class=x2>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td width=45 align=center>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
              <td align=left class=x2>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan=3 align=center valign=top>
                Lorem Ipsum
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Please feel free to suggest any idea or solution. Thank you.

Comment: Depending on the content of the table; it may not fit on the tiny mobile screen and may have to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Hm, i have couple lines of text and several small images (icons) in my table... 
Its little table, but i do not know how to make it responsive on mobile screen wthout horizontal scroll

Comment: A have a similar problem driving me crazy for days. Did you find any solutions?